# R - accessing dataframe column names passed as strings in function argument

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

with data like below

```
text = "
date,a,b
12/2/2019,18.1,0.017741935
12/2/2019,18.2,0.020967742
12/9/2019,16.7,0.020322581
12/9/2019,16.9,0.019677419
12/3/2019,18.1,0.017741935
12/3/2019,18.8,0.020967742
12/10/2019,16.2,0.020322581
12/10/2019,16.1,0.019677419
"
df1 = read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T)
```

Need to run a similar operation on multiple similar dataframes but with differed column names, so a function makes sense. The function does a scatter plot of two variables using `dplyr` and `ggplot` like below.

```
dplyrGgFn = function(df, colNameX, colNameY) {

  # get average Y value for each x value point to be used
  df = df %>%
    select(colNameX, colNameY) %>%
    mutate(colNameX = round(colNameX,0)) %>%
    group_by(colNameX) %>%
    summarise(colNameY = mean(colNameY))

  # 
  return(
    ggplot(df, aes_string(x=colNameX, y=colNameY)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = "blue"))
  )

}
```

And call like `dplyrGgFn(df1, "a", "b")`

Obviously this function throws error and as you may see the problem is with accessing the column name variables passed as strings in the function call.

```
Error in round(colNameX, 0) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

what is the recommended approach to handle strings passed as arguments for column names ? looking for generic answer as it could be applicable for a multiple cases.

**Update:**

user @Onyambu commented to have a non-function version as starting point - adding that.

```
df1 = df1 %>%
    select(a, b) %>%
    mutate(a = round(a,0)) %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarise(b = mean(b))

ggplot(df1, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = "blue"))
```

Comment: you should learn about `quasi quotations` and `lazy evaluations`.

Comment: Also how do you change colNameY yet it is a grouping variable at the very end? You should think of creating a grouping varible. Can you post a how you would do this without the function?. Try that then you could think of the function later

Comment: @Onyambu - updated the question with a non-function version of doing this. Also corrected grouping variable mistake - would you provide your expert guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it is not clear what you are trying to do but here is something which might help if you want to pass quoted values in the function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

dplyrGgFn = function(df, colNameX, colNameY) {
    x_col <- sym(colNameX)
    y_col <- sym(colNameY)
    df %>%
      group_by(!!x_col) %>%
      summarise(colNameY = mean(!!y_col)) %>%
      ggplot() + aes(!!x_col, y= !!y_col) + geom_point()
}

dplyrGgFn(df1, "a", "b")
```

Note that `aes_string` has been deprecated in favor of `sym` and `aes(color = "blue")` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

---

To pass unquoted variables use `{{}}`.

```
dplyrGgFn = function(df, colNameX, colNameY) {
  df %>%
    group_by({{colNameX}}) %>%
    summarise(colNameY = mean({{colNameY}})) %>%
    ggplot() + aes({{colNameX}}, y= {{colNameY}}) + geom_point()
}

dplyrGgFn(df1, a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed the group_by(y) to group_by(x), it seems what you intended to do. Otherwise, it is not clear (as also mentioned in a comment).

The following code should help you to understand how to pass variable names `dplyr` code within functions.

```
dplyrGgFn = function(df, colNameX, colNameY) {

  # get average Y value for each x value point to be used
  df = df %>%
    select(!!colNameX, !!colNameY) %>%
    mutate(!!colNameX := round(!!as.name(colNameX), 0)) %>%
    group_by(!!as.name(colNameX)) %>%
    summarise(!!colNameY := mean(!!as.name(colNameY)))
  # 
  return(
    ggplot(df, aes_string(x=colNameX, y=colNameY)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = "blue"))
  )
}
```

Comment: you have used `!!colNameX` and `!!as.name(colNameX)` in different places - what's the difference. Also see using `:=` instead of `=` - would you please add the relevance of these.

Comment: Use `:=` for dynamical assignments with likes of `!!colNameX` on the left-hand side while `!!as.name(colNameX)` are on the right.

Comment: whats the difference between `!!colNameX` and `!!as.name(colNameX)`, also why to use `:=` over `=`  ?